# Select one record from query response based on condition | function postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to sql/postgres and trying to write a postgresql query which will return one record from a DB table

**My current query:**

```
select * from table 
where key = 'WITS' or substring(key, 1,1) = substring('WITS', 1, 1);
```

**Response:**

- WHITE
- WITS

**Problem:**
I want to update this query in a way that it returns only **WITS** in response. 
*i.e. if key is matched, return the record else match the first character*

I think postgres function may be of some help in this regard and i can add this if/else condition in that.

How to do it?

**Sample Data:**
keys = WITS, WHITE, Abhis, Amanda, Blue, Delta

Table attched in screenshot

[image]

Comment: Why not simply use `where key = 'WITS'`?

Comment: because I can have different keys as well.  e.g Amanda

Answer (score 0):

Postgres example with conditions:

```
SELECT a,
       CASE WHEN a=1 THEN 'one'
            WHEN a=2 THEN 'two'
            ELSE 'other'
       END
    FROM test;
```

Your case can be probably something like:

```
 SELECT *,
      CASE
        WHEN key = 'WITS' THEN key
        ELSE substring(key, 1,1)
      END 
    FROM table;
```

Comment: Will return both WITS and WHITE.

Answer (score 0):

Even after the chat I'm not really sure about your use case, but perhaps this query will lead you to an answer.

Sample data

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t (key TEXT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('WITS'),('WHITE'),('Abhis'),('Amanda'),('Blue'),('Delta'),('Woman');
```

Query

```
SELECT CASE WHEN key = 'WITS' THEN key
 ELSE substring(key, 1,1) END 
FROM t
WHERE key = 'WITS' OR substring(key, 1,1) = substring('WITS', 1, 1)
ORDER BY (key='WITS') DESC;

 substring 
-----------
 WITS
 W
 W
(3 Zeilen)
```

*The answer provided by @Gordon Linoff might be what you're looking for.*

Comment: Didn't work if the input is 'Amanda' 
In that case it should return the row with Key = A

Comment: @FayzaNawaz so whats the problem with `SELECT 
 CASE WHEN key = 'WITS' THEN key
 ELSE substring(key, 1,1)
END FROM t;`? It returns either `WITS` or the first character of the string

Comment: it returns all the records.

Comment: Can you add exactly what you expect from the given sample you provided in your last edit?

Comment: if the key is matched, return the record else match the first character of the key.

Comment: in my last edit, if the key is WITS, response should be 'WITS'. if it's Woman, response should be 'WHITE'. If it's 'Amanda', response should be 'A'

Comment: So for every key that is not `WITS` it should return `WHITE`? Or only keys that are not `WITS` and begin with a `W`? e.g. `SELECT 
 CASE 
   WHEN key = 'WITS' THEN key
   WHEN substring(key, 1,1) = 'W' THEN 'WHITE'
 ELSE substring(key, 1,1)
END FROM t;`

Comment: if the full key is not matched, it should search for some key where the first letter matches.
so if the key will be starting with "a", it will return A. or if starting with 'w', then return wits or white anything (because both matches the first character here.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205431/discussion-between-jim-jones-and-fayza-nawaz).

Answer (score 0):

If you want *one* row returned, the simplest method is:

```
select *
from table 
where substring(key, 1,1) = substring('WITS', 1, 1);
order by (key = 'WITS') desc
limit 1;
```

If you want multiple rows when there is no direct match, then one method (without subqueries) is:

```
select *
from table 
where substring(key, 1,1) = substring('WITS', 1, 1);
order by rank() over (order by (key = 'WITS') desc)
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myFunction(name varchar) 
RETURNS TABLE (result varchar) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tt WHERE key = name)) THEN
       RETURN QUERY SELECT key as result FROM tt WHERE key = name;
   ELSE
       RETURN QUERY SELECT key as result FROM tt WHERE substring(key, 1,1) = substring(name, 1, 1);
   END IF;
END;
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM myFunction('WITS');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a UNION query:

```
select * 
from the_table 
where key = 'WITS' 
union all
select * 
from the_table 
where key = substring(key, 1,1) = substring('WITS', 1, 1)
and not exists (select *
                from the_table 
                where ky = 'WITS')
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a function and added multiple queries in it. That worked for me:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myFunc(key varchar(250))  RETURNS varchar(250) AS $$
DECLARE
  rec varchar(250);
BEGIN
  select record INTO rec from table sk where sk.key = key;

  if (rec IS NOT NULL) then  return rec;
  end if;

  select record INTO rec from table sk where substring(sk.key_pattern, 1,1) = substring(key, 1, 1);
  if (rec IS NOT NULL) then  return rec;
  end if;

  return '';

END;$$
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Used as:
select * from getKeyTranslation(1, 'WATS') as translation;